How to write python equivalent of md5 calculation in pyspark
For the following pyspark code, how to write python which give exactly same result
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

columnlist = ['col1','col2','col3']

result = f.md5(f.concat(*[f.coalesce(f.when(f.col(hashcol) == '', f.lit(None))  .otherwise(f.concat(f.col(hashcol), f.lit('|'))), f.lit('|')) for hashcol in columnlist])

Whatever i try its getting too long, which i dnt prefer. Is it possible to get it done in min code?
